# How to check if a vector 3 is in a vector 3 array c#

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

Here is the relevant code. I want to check if the current spawn location is in the last spawns array.

`lastSpawns` is an array of `Vector3`'s.

```
//Generate Level 
while(cubeSpawns != 100)
 {
     currentSpawnLocation = new Vector3(Random.Range(-5, 5), Random.Range(-5, 5), Random.Range(-5, 5));
     if (currentSpawnLocation != lastSpawns)
     {
         GameObject cubeClone = (GameObject)Instantiate(Cubes[Random.Range(0,Cubes.Length)], transform.position + currentSpawnLocation, Quaternion.identity);
         currentSpawnLocation = lastSpawns[cubeSpawns];
         cubeClone.transform.parent = CubeClones;
         cubeSpawns = cubeSpawns + 1;
     }
 }
```

Comment: This code won't even compile. Have you even tried researching this (e.g.: typing "C# array contains" into a search engine)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the static [`IndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7eddebat(v=vs.110).aspx) overload on the native `Array` class. It will return you the position an object is found in the array, or -1 if the object doesn't exist in the array.

So your code should go like this (you don't need the while loop anymore):

```
 currentSpawnLocation = new Vector3(Random.Range(-5, 5), Random.Range(-5, 5), Random.Range(-5, 5));
 if (System.Array.IndexOf(lastSpawns, currentSpawnLocation) == -1)
 {
     // the currentSpawnlocation is not found
     GameObject cubeClone = (GameObject)Instantiate(Cubes[Random.Range(0,Cubes.Length)], transform.position + currentSpawnLocation, Quaternion.identity);
     cubeClone.transform.parent = CubeClones;
     // I assume you want to store currentSpawnLocation in the array
     // for that I use your cubeSpawns variable to keep track of where 
     // we are in the array. If you use cubeSpawns for something else, adapt accordingly
     lastSpawns[cubeSpawns] = currentSpawnLocation;
     cubeSpawns = cubeSpawns + 1;
     // prevent going beyond the capacity of the array
     // you might want to move this in front of the array assingment
     if (cubeSpawns > lastSpawns.Length)   
     {
        // doing this will overwrite earlier Vector3
        // in your array
        cubeSpawns = 0;
     }
 }
```